# Show child attribute object list grid in admin

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I'd like to show the `order.customer.externalId` attribute using admin's template. I've tried the following:

```xml
    <mo:overrideItem ceilingEntity="org.broadleafcommerce.core.order.domain.Order">
      <mo:field name="name">
        <mo:property name="readOnly" value="false"/>
      </mo:field>
      <mo:field name="customer.externalId">
        <mo:property name="gridOrder" value="3500"/>
        <mo:property name="prominent" value="true"/>
        <mo:property name="friendlyName" value="External ID"/>
      </mo:field>
    </mo:overrideItem>
```

but I have no success.

Did anybody get something like this running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it looks like this is [set to `GRID_HIDDEN`](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/blob/45165c16f23b88bf35e4d427a3a173c45544b294/core/broadleaf-profile/src/main/java/org/broadleafcommerce/profile/core/domain/CustomerImpl.java#L144). Try re-setting it with this, and also turning `excluded=false`, since it's under an `@AdminPresentationToOneLookup`:

```
<mo:overrideItem ceilingEntity="org.broadleafcommerce.core.order.domain.Order">
  <mo:field name="name">
<mo:property name="readOnly" value="false"/>
  </mo:field>
  <mo:field name="customer.externalId">
    <mo:property name="gridOrder" value="3500"/>
    <mo:property name="prominent" value="true"/>
    <mo:property name="friendlyName" value="External ID"/>
    <mo:property name="visibility" value="NOT_SPECIFIED"/>
    <mo:property name="excluded" value="false"/>
  </mo:field>
</mo:overrideItem>
```